# Find the largest files on the system from the command line

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

I am working on a Linux production server and the client wants to be able to find the largest files on the system to make sure they are not taking up too much space.

I found this command: `sudo du -a / 2>/dev/null | sort -n -r | head -n 20`, but it gives the largest directories, not files.

Does anyone know what command can find the largest files?

Thanks

Comment: Try `find / -type f -print0 | du -h --files0-from=- 2>/dev/null | sort -r | head -n 20`

Comment: @fpmurphy, if you use `du -h` you'll want `sort -h -r`

Comment: @glennjackman.  You are correct. Typo on my part, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution using `find` should meet your requirements:

```
# find / -type f -print0 | du -h --files0-from=- 2>/dev/null | sort -h -r | head -n 20
```